# Business delegate handling an exception

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract

I'm confused in one of the line about Business delegate that says:

> Business delegate handle & abstract
>   any remote exception

What do they mean with the word "abstract" here? Is it just providing a details not how to implement them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out the Sun documentation yet?

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/BusinessDelegate.html

If you tie a client directly to a business service interface, that client may potentially have to change every time the business service changes.  In the scenario where you have one type of client using a service, that's not a big deal, but when you have a bunch of potentially different clients that all want to use the same service, it becomes more of a problem.  On top of that, all of your clients that want to use the service probably want to handle looking up the service and handling exceptions from the service in a similar fashion.

In order to mitigate this scenario, you pull all the details of exception handling and distributed lookup out of the individual clients ("abstract" it out) and pull it into a business delegate object.  All your clients can now use a business delegate to access the business service in a uniform way and when the business service changes, only your business delegate object has to change rather than all your individual clients.

That's kind of my understanding of the scenario.  Hopefully that clears things up for you.